# Строковая конкатенация при переводе в дургую систему счисления в PHP

Tags: php

Как реализовать строковую конкатенацию так, чтобы, при переводе числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную, переносился остаток от деления и число записывалось в двоичном виде?

Comment: У вас странный вопрос... Вы хотите сделать конкатенацию или перевести числа из одного формата в другой?

Comment: Допустим число 36 перевожу в двоичную систему, получается 100100. нужно сделать так, чтобы при делении на 2, остаток от деления записывался с конца

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[base-convert](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base-convert.php)

```
string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

Или это учебное задание?

upd. тогда так:

```
<?php

$in = 21; //число которое переводят в необходимую систему счисления

function myDec2Bin($number)
{
  $base = 2;//база

  $ost = 0;
  $del = 0;
  $out = "";
  $res = "";

  echo "=======\n<br>in  = $number; base = $base\n</br>=======</br>";
  for($i = $number; $i >= $base; ){
    $del = (int)($i/$base); //делим.
    $ost = $i - $del * $base;     // остаток от деления
    $res = $out;          //сохраняем предыдущую строку.
    $out = $ost.$res;     //добавление в начало строки
    $i = $del;    //то что осталось
    echo "del = $del; ost = $ost; out = $out\n</br>";
  }

  $ost = $i;        
  $res = $out;          //сохраняем предыдущую строку.
  $out = $i.$res;      //остаток в начало строки.

  echo "=======\n<br>ost = $ost; out = $out\n</br>=======</br>";
  return $out;

}

$result = myDec2Bin($in);
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>";

?>
```

результат:

```
=======
in = 21; base = 2
=======
del = 10; ost = 1; out = 1
del = 5; ost = 0; out = 01
del = 2; ost = 1; out = 101
del = 1; ost = 0; out = 0101
=======
ost = 1; out = 10101
=======
result = 10101
```

Comment: учебное задание

Comment: проапдейтил ответ. ;) можно конечно оптимизировать, но для учебного задания в самый раз.

Comment: спасибо большое))). А как реализовать, чтобы можно было переводить любое другое число?

Comment: форму и передавать в скрипт POST/GET параметром необходимое число

Comment: еще раз спасибо большое за помощь)))